# Macro executes in whole BEFORE presenting intermediate steps

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Macro (working in all code) that performs various steps in various worksheets of a workbook (e.g. XYZ(1); XYZ(2); XYZ(3); ... ; XYZ(10)).

During these steps this Macro updates a specific cell in Worksheet A (where the user is positioned), growing like a "progress bar" (0% #########----> 100%).

When I execute this Macro "step-by-step" (using F8) I can see the progress bar "grow" from 0 to 100%.
But when clicking the Macro button, it executes the whole procedure and then updates that field with the full "progress bar" in 100%.

I believe I have to use "Application.ScreenUpdating =" with "True" and "False" to briefly update AND SHOW this update in Worksheet A, but it seems to only work when executing step-by-step. Could this be the problem? Whenever executing "without control", the Macro bypasses intermediate steps?....

To make things short, let's exemplify briefly...

User positioned in Worksheet A

Macro Button in Worksheet A

```
Sub MacroXYZ
   Dim...
   Dim...
   Dim PBAR as String
   Set...
   Set...
   PBAR = ""
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   ...code...
   ...code...
   For i = 1 to 10 
      Do this in Worksheet XYZ(i)
      Do that in Worksheet XYZ(i)
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      PBAR = PBAR & "#"
      Worksheets("A").cells(3,3).value = PBAR
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Next i
   ...code...
   ...code...
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any light on this matter will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: After the line `Worksheets("A").cells(3,3).value = PBAR` add one more line `DoEvents`. This will give Excel the time to update the progressbar value. BTW, I prefer using the Excel Status bar for the updates... [Application.StatusBar property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.statusbar)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, Siddharth, but the "DoEvents" command really shows what is going on, but for this to happen, I have to use "Application.ScreenUpdating = True" immediately before the command and "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" immediately after. By doing this, the Macro continues to work, but changes its focus to the worksheet where Data is being inserted (XYZ(1), XYZ(2)...), instead of staying in "Worksheet A" where I want to see the Progress Bar grow.... :(

Comment: `changes its focus to the worksheet where Data is being inserted (XYZ(1), XYZ(2)...),...` That is most probably because you are using `.Activate` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Nope. I took extra care in not using any ".Activate" in this Macro's code. The strangest  thing is, if I execute this code step-by-step (using VBA panel and the "F8" key), it works perfectly. It seems to me something like Excel says: "OK, so nobody is watching me... Let's wrap it up, remove the un-necessary things and get it done real quick..."

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Thanks for your interest, but I resolved the problem by adding...



         '--- Show Progress Bar ----------
         Application.ScreenUpdating = True
         WS1.Activate
         WS1.Range("E15").Value = MOSTRA
         DoEvents
         Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         '---------------------------------



Where "MOSTRA" is the string I use as the progress bar. Now I can see the Progress Bar growing, but the screen keeps flickering and all objects in this worksheet (buttons, controls, checkboxes) "disappear" during the Macro execution...